# Can a soprano leap 2 times in a row in the same direction?

Tags: voice-leading

[image]

Here is a bar where my soprano leaps a 5th then a 3rd in the same direction. the 5th is on the same chord but it doesnt change direction after. What are the guidelines for two consecutive leaps in chorale style harmony exercises?

Comment: There are certainly examples of actual chorales in which the melody leaps more than once in the same direction, regardless of whether the rules you are working with allow it.

Comment: I will refrain from jokes about track-and-field.

Answer (score 1):

Goetschius has some comments about this in the later pages of "Exercises in Melody Writing." (It's rather old, but the ideas can be easily applied in more modern contexts.)

The main problem with consecutive leaps in the same direction is creating too much space between the leaping voice and those below (or above) it. There are conditions for which leaps are fine. One of them (I think this may apply to your case.) occurs when a voice is outlining a "good" chord. The harmony is unchanged. Goetschius' definition of a "good" chord included I, ii, ii7, IV, II&, V7, V9. He points out that for V9 in minor, the augmented second between lower scale step 6 and the upper scale step 7 isn't that hard to sing. In C minor, the pattern D-F-G-Ab-B is fine.

Comment: The main problem for part writing but for melody writing it is supposed that consecutive leaps in the same direction make a poor melody. In my case I wonder if it applies since the 5th leap happens over the same chord

Answer (score 0):

While of course this all depends on which exact variant of "the rules" is being enforced, generally:

1. Individual leaps should almost certainly not be larger than an octave
   1a. Usually, smaller than a sixth or a fifth is even better
2. Dissonant intervals in leaps (thus, tritones, sevenths) should be avoided
3. Voice crossings and overlaps as a result of a leap should be avoided

And more specifically regarding consecutive leaps, now, depending on how strict "the rules" in question are:

4. Consecutive leaps are generally best avoided (stepwise movement, usually in contrary motion to the leap, is preferred, sometimes mandatory depending on the magnitude of the leap)
5. If you must, outlining a triad (or another chord position) is more OK than alternatives (one of my classes had this as "two consecutive leaps should not form a seventh together", which, if you consider all the possibilities that remain within less than an octave, pretty much forces the "outlining a chord" idea: 1-4-6; 1-3-5; 1-3-6)

So to take your example, and guessing the key signature (I assume the F is probably sharp, given there appears to be a B major chord underneath), this instance probably isn't OK (and if you play it, it will be rather odd as well, not least because of that but because you also have a dominant chord with no third, and some further issues up and downstream...). A simple solution which might help avoiding this would be to follow the general guidance of "keep common tones in the same voice": there's really no reason for that soprano to jump from an F# to a B...